# DDD: should local Entity identity include the parent's?

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity, local, identity

In DDD, **Entities** have this concept of *identity* that uniquely identifies every instance regardless of all the other properties. Usually this identity has to be unique among the BC in which the Entity live, but there is an exception.

Sometimes we need to create Aggregates that are not only made by the root Entity and some Value Objects but have one or more child / nested Entities (that I understand to be called *local Entities*). For this kind of Entities the identity has only to be locally unique i.e. unique among the Aggregate boundaries.

Given this, let's also consider the fact that are two way to model a *has-a* relationship in DDD, depending on the actual business needs: separate Aggregates or Aggregate Root + child Entities.

In the first case the "child" Aggregate of the relation has a reference to the identity of the parent one, which in turn usually has a factory method to create and return an instance of the child:

```
class ForumId extends ValueObject
{
  // let's say we have a random UUID here
  //  forum name is not a suitable identifier because it can be changed
}

// "parent" aggregate
class Forum extends AggregateRoot
{
  private ForumId _forumId;
  private string _name;

  method startNewThread(ThreadId threadId, string title): Thread
  {
    // make some checks, maybe the title is not appropriate for this forum
    //  and needs to be rejected

    ...

    // passing this forum's ID,
    return new Thread(this->_forumId, threadId, title)
  }
}

class ThreadId extends ValueObject
{
  // let's say we have a random UUID here
  //  thread title is not a suitable identifier because it can be changed
}

// "child" aggregate
class Thread extends AggregateRoot
{
  private ForumId _forumId;
  private ThreadID _threadId;
  private string _title;
}
```

If we consider instead the second case, let's say because for some business reason we need to have `Thread` as a local entity of `Forum`, what is the correct way to identify it? Should `Thread` still contain the `ForumId` of the parent `Forum` or it is redundant since it will only live inside that specific `Forum` and never accessed outside?

Which way is better and more importantly why? May the data model (i.e. the database level) steer the decision toward one way or another, or should we still ignore it as per good DDD design?

```
class Forum extends AggregateRoot
{
  private ForumId _forumId;
  private string _name;
  private List<Thread> _threads;

  method startNewThread(string title): ThreadId
  {
    // or use and injected `ThreadIdentityService`'s `nextThreadId(ForumId)` method
    var threadId = this.generateNextLocalThreadId()
    var newThread = new Thread(/*this->_forumId, */ threadId, title)
    this._threads.append(newThread)
    return threadId
  }
}

// "child" aggregate - case 1
class Thread extends LocalEntity
{
  private ForumId _forumId;
  private ThreadID _threadId;
  private string _title;
}

// "child" aggregate - case 2
class Thread extends LocalEntity
{
  private ThreadID _threadId;
  private string _title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main purpose of having an aggregate is to make any change to this aggregate atomic.
The aggregate root contains the full child entity inside, for example Forum would have a collection of Threads.
Since the Thread is already inside a Forum wouldn’t make any sense having ForumId inside since the repository in charge of saving it would already know that id because we’d save the whole forum not a single thread.

Also wanted to add that Forum aggregate seems to be a huge aggregate, that implies some trade offs that you should take into account.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I had in mind, it seemed like a repetition to me! BTW do not worry about the big Aggregate since forum / thread was just an example to illustrate the issue I had. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: what about domain events? If we want the child class to raise an event, let's say by adding it to a private collection, how can I construct such an event? Let's say that the event is `ThreadRenamed`, and it contains the thread's ID and its name... but without the forum ID we cannot fully recognise this event, isn't it? So this seems to suggest a way to access the parent's ID from the child... or that the child should not raise its own events? But this does not seem right...

Comment: since the entry point is the aggregate root I'd place this logic in the aggregate root itself so it can also register this event, because to keep atomicity no one should be able to access directly to a child entity. So in this case we'd call Forum->renameThread(thread_id, new_thread_name)

Comment: So child / local entities should only have identity but no "event management"... but what if an action on the parent causes a method to be executed on each child? The event adding logic for the children will now be duplicated across the two methods... Contrived example but we can close a specific thread and this raises a ThreadClosed event, and the we can close the forum and have ForumClosed but also a lot of TheadClosed event, and now we have `::addDomainEvent(ThreadClosed)` in both the `Forum::closeThread` and `Forum::close` methods.

Comment: Good point actually, if in your case it fits better raising events from the child entity do it, I wouldn't take that as a mandatory rule, I've done it like that because was easy in my case. In yours, you could have the aggregate root pull events method that could iterate all the child entities to get their domain events too, or you could pull the domain events after doing the action to the child entity and save it to the events collection in the aggregate root. Not sure if I explained well enough :)

Comment: Yeah I understood your point! Moreover another options that I thought of is leave the raising of the "child event" in a `Root` (private) method and refactor the `closeThread` and `close` method to use that new common method so there is again no duplication.